# How to install .zip R package in ubuntu

Tags: r, package

I have converted the package_name.zip file created in windows to a package_name.tar.gz file using an on line converter.  I am following the following steps to build and install the package:

```
R CMD build brocolors
```

(Replace brocolors with the name of your package directory, which hopefully is also the name of your package.)

You’ll see something like this

```
$ R CMD build package_name
* checking for file 'package_name/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'brocolors':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* creating default NAMESPACE file
* building 'brocolors_0.1.tar.gz'

R CMD INSTALL package_name_1.2.tar.gz
```

This is exactly what I do (glyCount is the name of the directory where the .tar.gz file is.

```
R CMD build glyCount
* checking for file ‘glyCount/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* preparing ‘glyCount’:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
Warning in file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'man': No such file or directory
 ERROR
computing Rd index failed:cannot open the connection
```

I do not understand why the building of the package is not working.  Is it because the package has been created in windows?

There is not a file named man in the package directory. Is this file created only in linux when the package is created?

Thanks